# Why does `has_construct<Alloc, T, Args...>::value` give different values on gcc (false) and clang (true)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I am trying to implement `allocate_traits`, and then I am trying many methods and finally make it works well with gcc (>= 5), and the following is a class do the judgement about `allocate_traits::construct`

```
template <typename ...>
using type_helper = void;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct has_construct_helper {
    template <typename Alloc, typename = type_helper<
        decltype(declval<Alloc &>().construct
                 (declval<T *>(), declval<Args>()...))
    >> static constexpr true_type test(Alloc, int);

    template <typename Alloc> static constexpr false_type test(Alloc, ...);
};

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename... Args>
using has_construct =
decltype(has_construct_helper<T, Args...>::test(declval<Alloc>(), 0));
```

And I test it with an allocator that doesn't include `construct`, and it works well with gcc (>= 5), but clang (>= 3.7) give me `true`. Is this code  valid?

there is a whole file with the same error and may be simpler:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a6125c4796d4c0227cb

Comment: Can you at least name the error, and much better prepare an [MCVE]? Among other, MCVE means remove all code not needed to reproduce the issue; I'm pretty sure you can make a much simpler template(s) with the same problem.

Comment: The real question is "why does `has_c<t,int>::value` give different values on g++ (`false`) and clang++ (`true`)?"  It might be a good idea to delete everything else from the question

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ah, the issue is with `type_helper`. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: In any event, using `type_helper` is completely superfluous. You are just testing the well-formedness of the expression, not matching it against another type (like in partial specializations), so there's no point in coercing it to `void`.

Comment: @T.C. Do you mean just use `typename = decltype(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `type_helper` alias template. There used to be an ambiguity in the standard for how to handle unused variadic template parameters. Clang decided to just leave them alone, so your `decltype` expression is never actually checked, so SFINAE doesn't occur.

The simple fix is to defer to another trait so that the arguments are evaluated:

```
template <typename...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename...Ts> using type_helper = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

---

Here's a slightly simpler version of your code which uses the detection idiom for the SFINAE.

```
template <typename...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <typename...Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename, typename... Args>
struct has_construct_helper : std::false_type{};

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename... Args>
struct has_construct_helper<Alloc, T, 
    void_t<decltype(declval<Alloc &>().construct
                   (declval<T *>(), declval<Args>()...))>,
    Args...> : std::true_type
{};

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename... Args>
using has_construct = typename has_construct_helper<Alloc, T, void, Args...>::type;

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename... Args>
void doConstruct(std::true_type, Alloc &a, T *p, Args&&... args)
{
    a.construct(p, forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Alloc, typename T, typename... Args>
void doConstruct(std::false_type, Alloc &, T *p, Args&&... args)
{
    ::new (static_cast<void *>(p)) T(forward<Args>(args)...);
}


template <typename Alloc>
class allocator_traits {
public:
//...
    template <typename T, typename... Args> static
    void construct(Alloc &a, T *p, Args&&... args)
    {
        doConstruct(has_construct<Alloc,T,Args...>{}, a, p, forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
//...
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70a59e0b0df195d4)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have try several methods and become tired about this work.

Comment: Interesting, I don't recall clang having CWG1558 problems, but apparently it does...for default template arguments.